# JavaScript 3D icons

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, graph-visualization

I am using [3D Force directed graph](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) to visualize a graph database. I want to use custom 3D icons for graph nodes according to each node type, such as **persons**, **movies** and **buildings**. Currently the conical shapes represent persons while the cube shapes stand for movies.

[image]

Is there a tool available to create such 3D icons or figures of persons and buildings in JavaScript? Currently I'm using the geometrical shapes available in THREE.js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create 3D Icon Blender **(https://www.blender.org/)** and add this icon using three.js loader **(https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/ObjectLoader)**

Comment: Or you can build your own "icons", combining primitives.

Comment: @prisoner849 or if you're _really_ twisted, you can create your own custom shapes by manually defining geometry buffers. I've _never_ done that... ;)